# Did I find the normal line correctly?

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to find the normal line to the curve $f(x)=x^2-5$ at $x=2$.

I found that the tangent line at $x=2$ is $y=4x-9$.

From there, I figure by looking at it that the normal line is $y=-\frac{1}{4}(x+2)$

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to find the tangent as the gradient of the curve at $x=2$ is $(2x)_{\text{(at x=2)}}=4$

So, the gradient  of the normal is $\displaystyle \frac{-1}4$

So, the equation of the normal is $\displaystyle \frac{y-(-1)}{x-2}=-\frac14$

Comment: This is is the task, though: http://puu.sh/6Ognw.png

Comment: @Threethumb, clearly, we can avoid determining the equation of the tangent

Comment: It's a multiple choice test, I can't change the selection of answers.

Comment: @Threethumb, not sure if I've understood your last statement

Comment: It is only necessary to know the value of the slope of the tangent line - which is also called the gradient - in order to find the slope of the normal line. From there, use the point slope form of a line, using the fact that the line is determined at $x=2$; so $$y - f(2) = \frac{-1}{4} \left( x - 2 \right) .$$

Comment: I ran out of time, so I had to submit the test. $y=-\frac{1}{4}(x+2)$ was the right answer after all. At least according to the test.

@lab I was asking this question because I was given the question in a multiple choice test. There was only 4 possible answers to choose from, you can see them in the link from my first comment to this answer. The equation you gave me was not a choice on the test, so it can't be the right answer regardless. The answer had to be one of the four given to me by the test. The one in the OP turned out to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

lab Bhattacharjee and izœc have shown you how to use a standard form of equation for the normal through a point. That equation can be rearranged into the form you want.

There is another strategy you can use for multiple choice - identify the gradient of the normal as $-\frac 14$ and eliminate the answers which have the wrong gradient. Then check which line goes through the relevant point on the curve - here $(2,-1)$. Since there is a unique line of given gradient through a point, this will identify the answer without any algebraic manipulation.

The line of gradient $m$ through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is: $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0) \text{ or equivalently } m=\frac {y-y_0}{x-x_0}$$ which is the form given in lab's answer. This can be rearranged as: $$y=m\left(x+\frac{y_0-mx_0}m\right)$$ Your multiple choice answer is in the second form. The first form is easy to remember and standard - it simply expresses the gradient as the slope of a line through the given point. I would use the "substitute the point" method for multiple choice (because it is easy to get signs wrong in a hurry). If I wanted a non-standard form, I'd manipulate the standard version rather than trying to remember it.